# Android/Kotlin: How to create a class that uses a DBLocal class? Error message: Type mismatch require context

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I would like to create a general DB class that manage a local DB and another DB. I have a mistake, but I don't understand what is the problem...

**General class:**

```
class DBHandler {
    companion object {
        val sharedInstance = DBHandler() //gérer si sharedinstance est null pour éviter pb d'ecriture
    }

    fun methodToSelectData(strQuery: String, dataBase: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result:*/
    {
        print(message = strQuery)

        val dbLocal = DBLocal(this, null, null, 1) //pb on this line
        dbLocal.methodToSelectData(strQuery)
    }
}
```

**DB Class:**

```
class DBLocal(context: Context, name: String?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION)
{

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase)
    {
        print(DATABASE_NAME)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int)
    {

    }
    fun methodToSelectData(strQuery: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result:*/
    {

    }

    fun methodToInsertUpdateDeleteData(strQuery: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)*/
    {

    }
    companion object {
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "Local.db"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you use `methodToSelectData`method? In activity/fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DBLocal(
    context: Context,
    name: String?,
    factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?,
    version: Int
) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {

}
```

**Problem:** DBLocal class receive a Context as the first parameter, but when you call it from DBHandler class.

```
val dbLocal = DBLocal(this, null, null, 1) //pb on this line
```

You are passing `this` as DBLocal class which is not a Context of sub-classes of Context class. That why your app throws error.

> Error message: Type mismatch require context

**Solution:** The simple solution is pass a Context into the method which requires a Context to do job.

```
fun methodToSelectData(context: Context, strQuery: String, dataBase: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result:*/ {
    print(message = strQuery)

    val dbLocal = DBLocal(context, null, null, 1) //pb on this line
    dbLocal.methodToSelectData(strQuery)
}
```

And pass a context when calling DBHandler, for example in an activity or a service.

```
DBHandler.sharedInstance.methodToSelectData(this, "your query", "dataBase")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a context to `methodToSelectData`

```
fun methodToSelectData(context : Context, strQuery: String, dataBase: String)/*, completion: @escaping (_ result:*/
{
    print(message = strQuery)

    val dbLocal = DBLocal(context, null, null, 1) //pb on this line
    dbLocal.methodToSelectData(strQuery)
}
```